# Which "Security Mode" setting in DD-WRT?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, wifi-configuration

The wiki article here:

https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_security

says that:

> To keep things simple, the best options, in decreasing order of
>   preference, may be:
>
> 1. WPA2 + AES
> 2. WPA + AES (only if all devices support it).
> 3. WPA + TKIP+AES (only if all devices can support it).
> 4. WPA + TKIP
> 5. WEP (will only keep out people with none or poor experience in computers)
> 6. Disabled (no security)

I'm not sure what that translates to when actually choosing an option in router setup. For instance, in the current build there are four different WPA2 options in the "Security Mode" list. Can someone help?

It's a small home router. I don't need Enterprise mode.

[edit]

Okay, the first setting is called "Security Mode", and has nine options:

- Disabled
- WPA-PSK
- WPA2-PSK
- WPA2-PSK/WPA-PSK
- WPA-EAP
- WPA2-EAP
- WPA2-EAP/WPA-EAP
- RADIUS
- WEP

The second setting varies, but right now is called "WPA Algorithms" and has three options:

- CCMP-128 (AES)
- TKIP+CCMP (AES)
- TKIP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you're referring to is ancient. Most of it was written in 2007.

All modern devices support WPA2; unless you need to support *extremely* old wireless hardware (i.e, from 2004 or earlier), there's no need to fall back to WPA or WEP. As such, the security mode you probably want is "WPA2-PSK" (the third one on the list), and the default algorithm of CCMP-128 should be fine.

Comment: FYI the only method you want to use is the WPA2 method.  All other security options are insecure (they are basically plain text given current technology).  You actually want WPA3 but your hardware doesn't support that

Comment: Good catch. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

PSK stands for Pre-Shared Key.
If you don't know which one to choose, use WPA2-PSK.